# Can I use `tf.train.Supervisor`, `QueueRunner` and `tf.TFRecordReader` the same time in tensorflow? I got an "Graph is finalized" error

Tags: python, tensorflow, queue, runtime-error

I want to use `tf.TFRecordReader` and `QueueRunner` to read data, and use `tf.train.Supervisor` to save the model. But it didn't work. The error message is `RuntimeError("Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.")`

After @eaksan 's suggestion, I changed my code, but it still got the same error.

```
reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
...
label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(...)
sv = tf.train.Supervisor(logdir=None)
with sv.managed_session() as sess: # it didn't work
# with tf.Session() as sess: # it worked
  init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(),
               tf.local_variables_initializer())
  sess.run(init_op)
  # coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
  # threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
  threads = sv.start_queue_runners()
  try:
    # while not coord.should_stop():
    while not sv.should_stop():
      labels = sess.run(label_batch)
  except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
    print('Done training')
  finally:
    # coord.request_stop()
    sv.request_stop()

  # coord.join(threads)
  sv.wait_for_stop()
```

If I don't use `tf.train.Supervisor` and just use `tf.Session()`, the program works fine.

Comment: May be you should try calling employing `Supervisor` resources. It has its own `coordinator` and `start_queue_runners` method: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Supervisor#start_queue_runners and https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Supervisor#should_stop

Comment: @eaksan Thanks for your suggestion. But it didn't work.

Comment: I solved it! `tf.train.Supervisor` finalizes the graph. I shouldn't put the `init_op` within the `sess` scope. If `init_op` is defined before the `tf.train.Supervisor` , the program works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I post my answer here. Since `tf.train.Supervisor` finalizes the graph, `init_op` should be defined before the supervisor.

```
reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
...
label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(...)
init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(),
                   tf.local_variables_initializer())
sv = tf.train.Supervisor(logdir=None)
with sv.managed_session() as sess:
  sess.run(init_op)
  try:
    while not sv.should_stop():
      labels_np = sess.run(label_batch)
  except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
    print('Done training')
```